# Cache design question

Tags: caching, architecture

I'm working on building a data intensive application (analytics) for which I'm contemplating on whether designing a cache mechanism will give performance benefits. The application performs large frequent writes/updates. Would having a cache in this scenario make sense since updates are more frequent that look-up's? Is a cache used in high volume applications only when the size of the writes is small but frequent ? And in general, is size of writes a good indicator if the data is hot(most frequently accessed) ?

Comment: The answer to this question is so heavily dependent on your implementation that it's hard to answer.  Is the data in a database?  Which one (SQL/Oracle/etc.)  How big are the transactions?  I think in most cases you'll find that major RDBMS and analytics platforms (OBIEE, Microsoft Dynamics) already provide optimizations like the one you describe.

Comment: It seems like you're asking a lot of different questions here so it's hard to give a single answer; try rephrasing your questions and you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 4):

It has been my experience that "cache design" is a mixture of black art and hard science.  While hard science tends to be extremely predictable, this would make you think there's a formula, or at least a good rule of thumb, that you can apply to get useful results.  The black art part means that this is true, but is completely falsified while still managing to remain true.

One thing that remains invariant, however, is the need for comprehensive metrics.  You must, unconditionally, have extensive numbers based on profiling your application using Real World™ data.  Without this, you are simply guessing.  Decades of practical experience has shown time and time again that if you, as a programmer, are guessing about the nature of "where the performance problem is", you are 100% guaranteed to get it wrong.  Hence the need for hard, empirical data.

If you decide to pursue this, this first thing you must do, before you even start to "work on the problem", is find a way to gather empirical metrics.  Since you don't mention what language or tools you're using, I can't make specific recommendations, but virtually every tool chain has some profiling tools specifically designed to help you understand where your program is spending its time.

Next, your intuition in this case is probably correct.  You've already identified that your access patterns are likely to be "write biased".  A very common property of writes is that "they must happen before you can do anything else".  If this involves writing the data out to disk, you usually get bottlenecked on waiting for the disk i/o operation to complete, which is generally a real performance killer.  In this case, caching is unlikely to help at all as its not like you can "cache the write" because it has to happen.

There are some cases where "write caching" can help.  If your design and requirements allows the in memory version of data to be temporarily inconsistent with the on disk version of the data, it is often possible to "write combining".  This essentially involves delaying committing the data to disk based on the fact that for some access patterns, some non-consecutive writes will "update" the same "block" within a "flush to disk" window.

Another thing you *must* do when designing a caching system is take all your metrics, and your understanding of how your cache works, and then write performance tests that are maximally orthogonal to your design choices.  Ideally, your cache system should not noticeably degrade performance even in a worst case scenario, and there's always a worst case scenario.

**EDIT**

After re-reading your question, it's not clear if this is a performance problem you are experiencing right now, or one that you think you "might" experience.  If it's the later, re-read, at least three times, the second paragraph in my answer.  The ***only*** time you should be contemplating building a cache system is when you have identified, with hard empirical data, that you have a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is most often used in read-intensive applications. Using the cache to store updates/writes is risky b/c if the application crashes in any way the new updates/writes are lost. For this reason, the cache needs to be written to disk every so often (depending on the frequency of writes/updates).

You could write to the cache and have an asynchronous process write the cache to disk and refresh the cache periodically (again depending on the frequency of writes/updates). If this is asynchronous, the cache can still be used to serve reads/new writes.

Frequency, not size, of writes is typically an indicator of how hot the cache is.

Comment: but is it safe to assume that always the most frequently accessed data is small in size and would it hold true for e.g in case of a data-intensive application ??

Comment: I don't think size of each "record" is as important, it depends more importantly on how frequent the record is being read. If it is a big record but read frequently, you can cache it. If it is a small record but read frequently, you can also cache it. (Of course the record has to be small enough to fit in memory, otherwise you have to use other storage strategies)

Comment: @pan See my answer.  *Do not* make any assumptions.  Only use hard, empirical data.  A single, actual measurement is worth a thousand opinions.

Answer (score 0):

A cache increases transfer performance. A part of the increase similarly comes from the possibility that multiple small transfers will combine into one large block. But the main performance-gain occurs because there is a good chance that the same datum will be read from cache multiple times, or that written data will soon be read. A cache's sole purpose is to reduce accesses to the underlying slower storage. Therefore you should pay great attention to when and what you actually cache.

Comment: Maybe you should add some examples.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on many factors, but in general a caching strategy provides the most benefit when the number of reads (for given data) far exceeds the number of writes. The [EHCache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/introduction.html) has a good overview of introductory caching principles.